# Sublime Text 3 - ?send commands to sublime console

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I would like to extend Sublime functionality which would allow me to send text from any application to active Sublime Text window. I realized it is possible to add text from Sublime Console with the following command:

`view.run_command("insert", {"characters": "Hello World!"})`

Now I am wondering if there is any built-in solution to execute sublime console commands from external applications, ex. command-line interface to accept external commands? Else, I am considering it should be possible to set-up Python to run Socket server to listen for commands and accept input this way?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `subl` command that ships with Sublime allows you to execute arbitrary commands from the command line:

```
tmartin:dart:~> subl --help
Sublime Text build 3211

Usage: subl [arguments] [files]         Edit the given files
   or: subl [arguments] [directories]   Open the given directories

Arguments:
  --project <project>: Load the given project
  --command <command>: Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:  Open a new window
  -a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:  Don't activate the application
  -h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:     Show version and exit

Filenames may be given a :line or :line:column suffix to open at a specific
location.
```

The `--command` argument expects you to provide the command and any arguments required all in a single argument; for example:

```
tmartin:dart:~> subl --command "insert {\"characters\": \"Hello, World\"}"
```

This will work for any command, and just like the Sublime console, `TextCommand` commands target the current `view` and `WindowCommand` commands target the current `window`.

The `subl` command is a helper that gives it's command line arguments to the running instance of Sublime and terminates; in the case that Sublime is not already running, it starts Sublime first and then passes the arguments along.

In the case that Sublime isn't already running, the `--command` argument won't work because `subl` provides the argument as soon as Sublime starts, but it takes the plugin host some time to become available to commands (in Sublime you see this happening as a `plugins loaded` message in the console).

So, it's important that you either ensure Sublime is running before you do it, or you launch Sublime first, wait a second or so, and then provide the command.

Comment: Good answer. You should probably double-check against Build 3211's output to make sure all the commands are the same. I know `--safe-mode` is new, I'm not sure about the other features.

Comment: @MattDMo Ahh good catch, thanks; `--command` has  been around forever, but it's definitely a good idea to keep this to the currently released version.

Comment: I was not able to get the anticipated result in Windows environment. It results me error with parsing the command:

subl.exe --command "insert {'characters': 'Hello, World'}"
subl.exe --command "insert({'characters': 'Hello, World'})"

Unable to parse command: insert {'characters': 'Hello, World'}
Unable to parse command: insert({'characters': 'Hello, World'})

Comment: It seems it did not work from Powershell environment, but all was ok once run from the Command prompt. Thanks for finding this and probably the best solution for my use!

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Windows CMD. I get the following error in the terminal: `Unable to parse command: insert {"characters": "Hello`.

Comment: It works here; are you using actual `cmd`? Different shells require different quoting; this one doesn't without tweaks in PowerShell, for example.